# How do I analytically sum all the values of a continuous function on some interval within its domain?

Tags: limits

Hello dear mathematical community.

I was wondering if anybody could point me to an answer on the question how to analytically add a function's values within its domain, please. I.e., what is the analytical formula for it? Or maybe such a summation doesn't exist?

Let me show an example of what I mean.

Consider a function $y(x)$. Let it be a straight line: $y=x$. Consider an interval, say, $x \in [0,5]$. I want to take the values of the function at every point within this interval and add them together: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n}y(x_n), ~~ for ~ all ~ x \in [0,5]$$
What would an analytical formula for such infinite sum be? Can I express it through an integral somehow? Is it something known? Or is it just nonsense?

Thank you in advance.

Ivan

---

**ANSWER**

To figure out the answer on my question, see the comment below by @Henry in combination with the answer by @EricTowers. Simplifying a lot: multiply the limit I showed by the interval (which gives us the definition of integral) and then divide it by the same interval (which gives us the definition of average). In one word, the limit I showed is equivalent to finding an average value of the function on the interval.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does $n$ mean?  In general, any uncountable sum of positive terms diverges.

Comment: This is what leads to integration.  In your example you might in a handwaving way say the average value of $y(x)$ is in a sense $2.5$.  Obviously summing an infinite number of these is infinite, but you are doing this over an interval of length $5$ so you might regard $5\times 2.5=12.5$ as meaningful in some way.  And $\int\limits_{x=0}^5 y(x) \, dx=12.5$ here

Comment: @lulu thank you for the hint on the theorem about the divergence of an uncountable sum, I totally forgot about it. $n$ is a number of a point. Take the first point $n=1$ which is $x=0$, find $y$ at this point. Take the next (adjacent) point $n=2$, find $y$ there, add it the previous y and so on till $x=5$ and $n=\infty$.

Comment: But there is no such thing as "the next adjacent point". The real line doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Henry Wow! That's a stunning revelation to me! I, definitely, need to think about it. Thank you. One thing I can point out is that $\int\limits_{x=0}^5 y(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n}y(x) \Delta x$ by definition of integral. And it is that $\Delta x$ that I can't seem to get into the limit that I showed in my question that will make it an integral. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you're right. I admit: I used slang language in my comment. I used it for brevity. More correctly: divide the interval on a finite number of adjacent intervals $\Delta x$. Assume that $y$ takes some constant value within each interval. Sum all the $y$ values in the limit of $\Delta x$ going to zero. Which's equivalent to the number of finite intervals $n$ going to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sum
$$  \sum_{q \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} 1  \text{,}  $$
the sum of one copy of $1$ for each rational number in the interval $[0,1]$.  This sum diverges to $\infty$ -- for any proposed upper bound of the sum, $N$, any partial sum containing at least (the floor of) $N+1$ terms exceeds that bound.  Since there are infinitely many rationals in $[0,1]$, the partial sums exceed (and remain forever above) any bound one picks.  That is, this sum diverges to $\infty$.

In fact, if you sum infinitely many summands, each greater than $\varepsilon > 0$, the sum diverges.  Similarly if each term is less than $- \varepsilon < 0$, diverging now to $-\infty$.

If it turns out that the domain of $f$ is a finite set, then one can, of course, sum the finite set of values $f$ takes as its input ranges over its domain.  For instance, suppose the domain of $f$ is $X \subset \Bbb{R}$ (or a subset of some other number system) and $|X|$, the cardinality of $X$, is finite.  Then the sum of the value of $f$ is what you think it is
$$  \sum_{x \in X} f(x)  \text{.}  $$

One can also write that as an integral in terms of the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure).

There is a sensible notion of the average value of a function, where we can (in the countable case) balance the growth of the partial sums against the number of terms in the sum...

The average value of a function, $f$, integrable on $[a,b]$ on any interval $[c,d]$ with $a \leq c < d \leq b$ is
$$  \frac{1}{d-c}\int_c^d f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$

Notice that, much like when one averages a list of $n$ numbers one sums up the values and divides by the length of the list, here we integrate the values and divide by the length of the interval.

This works just fine if the domain of $f$ is a finite union of intervals.  Even if an interval has one or both endpoints open, we can use limits to "sneak up" on those open endpoints -- see [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).  One can also use this method if the domain is a finite union of intervals extending to $-\infty$, $\infty$, or both, although in such an instance we must remember to include the $\frac{1}{d-c}$ in the limit, for instance,
$$  \lim_{c \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{1}{d-c} \int_c^d f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$

(As an exercise, take $f(x) = 1$ in that example.  The value of the integral is always $d-c$, so the value of the limit is $1$.  But if we try the same process on $  \frac{1}{d--\infty} \lim_{c \rightarrow -\infty} \int_c^d f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $, nothing useful is obtained.)

Life can get more difficult if the domain of $f$ is sufficiently "complicated".  For instance, if the domain of $f$ is [unmeasurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set), there may be no intelligible notion of average value, or at the very least, one must generalize what one means when one says "average".

Comment: @ErikTowers thank you very much for the response! I learnt a lot from it. I'm wondering about your remark that the sum $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ can be written as an integral in terms of counting measure. I've read about the counting measure. I'm getting this: $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \lim_{X \to 0} \sum \mu (X)$ where $\mu (X)$ is a measure of $X$. I can't seem to make an integral of this limit.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh : Let $\mu(X)$ be the counting measure for $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$.  Then the (Lebesgue) integral is $$  \sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \int_{x \in X} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)  \text{.}  $$  Recall: Riemann integrals "divide area" into rectangles whose width we take to $0$ in the limit.  Lebesgue integrals "divide area" into (set width)-cross-height whose height we take to $0$ in the limit.  Lebesgue integration wants to know the measure of the set to know what width to use.